# Programmatically set screen density on Android

Tags: android

I'm writing a game which I want to run on medium and high densities (320x480 and 480x800). In order to run the app on both densities, I had to set support-screens param like this.-

```
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />
```

My problem is, in some 2nd generation devices (i.e. HTC Desire), the game runs on hd density, but the performance is a little poor, so I'm trying to 'force' medium density for those devices.

I've managed to get the current density like this.-

```
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics(); 
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
```

and DisplayMetrics class seems to have a 'setTo' method, but not sure if it fits my need, nor how exactly should I use it. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have not much idea about it , but you can try this:

Just use a full screen layout, and inside define another layout that has the size you want. Kind of like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="200dip" 
        android:layout_height="150dip">
        <Button android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I put a button in there just to show where the content goes.

thanks

Comment: If you are using Windows and know how to use JNI, Microsoft provides C++ Win32 function calls to do this: ChangeDisplaySettingsEx() and EnumDisplaySettings().

Comment: Thanks for your answer Hemant, but I guess I didn't explain myself. My game is already correctly configured for mid and high res, and everything looks fine on both. My problem is about performance on 'old' devices that runs the game on Hi res, that's why I need to force that those devices run on mid res. Thanks.

Comment: Ups, sorry, didn't seen your second comment. I'm using a java game framework, not sure if I can have access to those c++ functions, but I'll give them a try. Thanks!